# Custom UIView not working in Xamarin

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to subclass UIView using Xamarin but don't seem to be getting the results I expect.  To keep things simple, I have the following class:

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace ExerciseTracker.iOS.Views
{
    [Register("CustomView")]
    public class CustomView : UIView
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

A breakpoint is set on the `base.Draw(rect);` line.  A view exists in my Storyboard layout with its class set to `CustomView`.

[image]

However, when the app is run and the page is shown, the breakpoint is never hit, and the breakpoint it displayed as though it will never be hit.

[image]

This is using Visual Studio for Mac v7.1.5.  Is there anything I'm missing here? It seems like it should be quite simple, but I've been stuck for a few hours on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a construct with `IntPtr` parameter in `CustomView` class, like this:

```
public CustomView(IntPtr p): base(p)
{
    //Your initialization code.
}
```

Then this class can be used in storyboard directly.

More details you can refer to this Xamarin official documentation:
[Walkthrough - Using Custom Controls with the Xamarin Designer for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/).

Comment: I thought I had tried that previously without success, but somehow I ended up tonight with a second `designer` partial file, which had that constructor as well as a `ReleaseDesignerOutlets()` method.  Not sure why, but it's working now and I don't dare try much experimentation at this stage.